# ModelMapper java 8 mappings by lambda

Tags: java, modelmapper

I have a problem with [Getting started](http://modelmapper.org/getting-started/) example from ModelMapper with Java8. They show that using their library you can define mappigs like

```
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

modelMapper.addMappings(mapper -> {
    mapper.map(src -> src.getBillingAddress().getStreet(), Destination::setBillingStreet);
    mapper.map(src -> src.getBillingAddress().getCity(), Destination::setBillingCity);
});
```

what obviously doesn't work and what's more cannot work since `ModelMapper` is not generic (so you cannot infer `src` and `dst` types)

```
public class ModelMapper {
    ...
}
```

and what's more `map()` method does not accept functional interface but `PropertyMap` object

```
public abstract class PropertyMap<S, D> {
    ...
}
```

I've checked [ModelMapper Github](https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper) page to see examples but it seems that they are using Java6/7 approach everywhere... :) Why then there is such example for Java8 in *Getting started* if it is not working and has no chance to work?

Have you ever investigated this? What am I doing wrong?

**I use ModelMapper 2.3.0**

---

**EDIT**

it should be

```
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
modelMapper.createTypeMap(Order.class, OrderDTO.class)
   .addMappings(mapper -> {
       mapper.map(src -> src.getBillingAddress().getStreet(), OrderDTO::setBillingStreet);
       mapper.map(src -> src.getBillingAddress().getCity(), OrderDTO::setBillingCity);
});
```

It seems that in official tutorial they named `modelMapper` TypeMap instance not ModelMapper :)

Comment: Hope this will help :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49003929/how-to-use-explicit-map-with-java-8-and-modelmapper

Comment: @manfromnowhere - thank you very much! I really have no idea why I couldn't find it before...