# Using ModelMapper on different data types with same attribute name

Tags: java, spring-boot, model, converters, modelmapper

I have two classes say `Animal` & `AnimalDto`
I want to use `ModelMapper` to convert Entity to DTO and vice verca.
But the classes are supposed to have different data types for a few attributes having similar name.
How do I achieve this?

**Animal.java**

```
public class Animal {    
    int category;    
    String color;    
    int age;
}
```

**AnimalDto.java**

```
public class AnimalDto {    
    String category;    
    int color;    
    int age;
}
```

---

currently I'm manually transforming as such:

```
class AnimalTransformer {
    private static Category[] categories = Category.values();    
    private static Color[] colors = Color.values();    

    animalEntityToDto(Animal animal) {
          AnimalDto animalDto = new AnimalDto();    
          animalDto.setAge(animal.getAge());
          animalDto.setCategory(categories[animal.getCategory()].toString());
          animalDto.setColor(Color.valueOf(animal.getColor()).ordinal());
    }

    animalDtoToEntity(AnimalDto animalDto) {
          Animal animal = new Animal();    
          animal.setAge(animalDto.getAge());
          animal.setCategory(Category.valueOf(animalDto.getCategory()).ordinal());
          animal.setColor(colors[animalDto.getColor()].toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you presented might not be the best part of model mapper in fluency especially because converting `enum`s that have some special difficulties what comes to using generics.

Anyway this is possible with `Converter` or usually `AbstractConverter`.

You did not provide examples of your enums so I create most simple example enums:

```
enum Color {
    PINK;
}
```

and

```
enum Category {
    MAMMAL;
}
```

To convert **Integer** `Animal.category` to **String** `AnimalDto.category`, a converter could be like:

```
public class CategoryToStringConverter extends AbstractConverter<Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String convert(Integer source) {
        return Category.values()[source].toString();
    }
}
```

And to convert **String** `Animal.color` to **Integer** `AnimalDto.category`, a converter could be like:

```
public class ColorToOrdinalConverter extends AbstractConverter<String, Integer> {
    @Override
    protected Integer convert(String source) {
        return Color.valueOf(source).ordinal();
    }
}
```

Usage would be like:

```
mm.createTypeMap(Animal.class, AnimalDto.class).addMappings(mapper -> {
    mapper.using(new CategoryToStringConverter()).map(Animal::getCategory, 
        AnimalDto::setCategory);
    mapper.using(new ColorToOrdinalConverter()).map(Animal::getColor, 
        AnimalDto::setColor);
});
```

This is the part of converting from `Animal` to `AnimalDto`. Converting vice versa of course needs mappings of its own which I do not present here because I think the point came clear.

For one class the way you do it now  might be better but if you need to convert `Category` & `Color` in many places like this then you should consider using converters that are reusable.